# Warning: Only the first byte will be assigned to the string offset

Tags: php, php-8

The following code was working just fine in PHP 7 so why am I seeing this warning in PHP 8?

```
$str = 'xy';
$str[0] = 'bc';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of PHP 8 trying to replace a string offset with more than one byte using square array brackets style will emit a `warning`.

So you just need to remove the extra byte (`c` in this case)

```
$str = 'xy';
$str[0] = 'b';
```

Or if you really want to replace `x` with `bc` you can use [substr_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

```
$str = 'xy';
var_dump(substr_replace($str, 'bc', 0, 1)); // output: string(2) "bcy"
```

**Note:** this function accepts byte offsets, not code point offsets.

Answer (score 2):

Actually code works the same as in PHP 7.4. The only difference is that now it throws Warning.

```
$str = 'xy';
$str[0] = 'bc';

var_dump($str); // string(2) "by"
var_dump(phpversion()); // string(6) "7.4.10"
```

PHP 8

```
var_dump($str); // string(2) "by"
var_dump(phpversion()); // string(10) "8.0.0beta4"
```

As [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) says:

> Internally, PHP strings are byte arrays. As a result, accessing or
> modifying a string using array brackets is not multi-byte safe, and
> should only be done with strings that are in a single-byte encoding
> such as ISO-8859-1.

If you want to insert all bytes from replacement string in a destination string you can use:

```
$str = 'xy';

function chars_replace(string $str, string $replacement, int $indexAt)
{
    return substr_replace($str, $replacement, $indexAt, $indexAt + strlen($replacement));
}

var_dump(chars_replace($str, 'bc', 0)); // string(2) "bc"
```

However it will not work with multibyte encoding.

If you want to replace only one char then you can use:

```
$str = 'xy';
$str[0] = substr('bc', 0, 1);

var_dump($str); // string(2) "by"
```